# Column Not Found SQL Error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I know this question has been asked here before, but I swear something strange is happening here. I am executing the following SQL command

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT category FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "user_messages_status_redux WHERE user_id = " . (int)$user_id . " ORDER BY category";
```

Before I run the query I echo it to the screen and get the following

```
SELECT DISTINCT category 
FROM user_messages_status_redux 
WHERE user_id = 1 ORDER BY category
```

I get this error everytime:

> Notice: Error: Unknown column 'category' in 'field list' Error No:
>   1054

I have checked and rechecked the SQL and it executes perfectly in phpmyadmin. Only thing strange is I created this field after the table was created, but that should not matter.

Comment: do you have `category` column in table `user_messages_status_redux` ??

Comment: do you have a column named `category` in your table? also try quoting fieldname with backtick `

Comment: Yes, I just added a single quote around both instances of category and it worked, but I don't know why that would matter. Category isn't a sql command

Comment: I don't quote my fields anywhere else in the project and it works fine

Comment: Not quote, backtick.  The character below the ~ (tilde) key.  Its used in mysql to denote a column.

Comment: Weirder still the back tick does not work only the single quote???

Comment: If you quote it it will give you the value "category" not the column `catagory`.  See this fiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/98d5aa/4

Comment: What is the value of `DB_PREFIX`?  Its not appending to your sql string.  You REALLY need to avoid string concatenation and use prepared statements.  You're open to sql injection attacks if you dont.

Comment: DB_PREFIX is empty. I know it's not the best way, but this is an opencart mod so I am following 1.5.6 standards... @paqogomez I agree it should work that way but backticks give error every time. Only with this one query. Very Very Strange